# Read line from stdin to pointer array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to read line from stdin and store it in a pointer array, when I print the array I get the last entered value, the other values are replaced by the last entered value. The `if` statement works the first time only, after that it comparison doesn't come `true`. How can I read a line into pointer array?

```
void read_line(int fd, char *s)
{
    char line[100];
    char *list[100];
    int i = 0;

    while ((read(1, line, 100)))
   {
        if (!strncmp(line, s, strlen(line) - 1))
            break;
        else
            list[i++] = line;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (list[i])
    {
        write(fd, list[i], strlen(list[i]));
        i++;
    }
}
```

I call the function

```
read_line(1, "exit");
//if I type more words before typing exit, then type exit program doesn't terminate
```

Comment: You store the same pointer to `line` for every entry. Next entry, all the previous point to same string. Consider using `strdup`.

Comment: You should zero-initialize `list` with `char *list[100] = { 0 };`

Comment: `char line[100]; char *list[100];` --> `char line[100] = "";char *list[100] = {NULL};`, `else
            list[i++] = line;` --> `list[i++] = strdup(line); memset(line, 0, sizeof line);`,

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: `read(1` --> `read(0` ?

Comment: `read` doesn't read a string. It reads a bunch of characters. But a string is a bunch of characters *plus a null terminator*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should ensure that `read` did not fail by checking its return value:

```
while ((read(1, line, 100)) > 0)
```

Then you must copy `line` content in `list[i++]` using `strdup`, otherwise all list items will end up with the last value pointed by `line`.

Finally, what do you expect to happen when `read` reaches the limit of your buffer? You might want to handle that as well.

Code could look like this:

```
#define SIZE 100
void read_line(int fd, char *s)
{
    char line[SIZE];
    char *list[SIZE] = { 0 };
    int i = 0;
    ssize_t retval;
    while ((retval = read(1, line, SIZE)) > 0)
   {
        if (retval == SIZE)
            // adapt to the desired behavior here... for now we'll abort
            break;
        else if (!strncmp(line, s, strlen(line) - 1))
            break;
        else
            list[i++] = strdup(line);
        memset(line, 0, SIZE);
    }
    i = 0;
    while (list[i])
    {
        write(fd, list[i], strlen(list[i]));
        i++;
    }
}
```